# What is the significance of the dogs being named Hamlet and Ophelia?

Tags: name-significance, allusions, hamlet, cinda-williams-chima, the-heir-chronicles

In *The Dragon Heir*, from Cinda Williams Chima's *The Heir Chronicles*, Madison has two golden retrievers who are named Hamlet and Ophelia. One does not name anything "Hamlet" in a book by accident. In addition, the books have their fake historical background in the Wars of the Roses, so Shakespeare's homeland already figures in. Thus, what is the meaning/significance of these names?